# Ferrite bead selection and simulations for a 2.4 GHz ESP32 3V3 power line

Tags: ltspice, simulation, ferrite-bead

I want to be able to filter the 3V3 power line going out of the ESP32 MCU. Since this "may" have a frequency around 2.4GHz (Wifi or Bluetooth antenna). This may then affect other components that also need the 3V3 power from the same net. I have implemented the below circuit thus far:

[image: schematic]

I then simulated this on LTSpice:

[image]

I first choose a general ferrite bead with the below specs:

[image]

The results of the simulation are below:

[image]

[image]

**My questions:**

1. Am I using the correct approach to simulate the ferrite bead?
2. From the results the attenuation is not sufficient, is there a way to calculate the values for the inductance, capacitance, and resistance so I can manually enter these values for the ferrite bead?

***Edit 1:***

I realized the frequency to attenuate was 2.4GHz and not 2.4MHz

Here is the simulation with the 2.4GHz frequency.

[image]

[image]

This Ferrite bead seems to be doing the job (I just need to confirm the current).

***Edit 2:***

Simulation results with modeling the capacitor with ESR and series inductance.

[image]

[image]

**Edit 3:**

Capacitors used:

1. 22pF:C0201C220K8GACTU (ESR=0.149, ESL=28.1p)
2. 0.1uF: C1206C104J3GACTU (ESR=0.0089, ESL=19.8p)
3. 1uF: C1206C105K3RACTU (ESR=0.0124, ESL=0.3p)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Generally speaking, the only way to reliably do this is to assemble a test coupon with the passive parts laid out same as they'll be in the product, with connectors for network analyzer installed. The connect the thing to a network analyzer, and determine exactly what the response is. Spice is garbage in = garbage out: the results are only as good as the device models supplied by the vendor. If you're not getting spice models from the manufacturer for each passive part that you're using, then you're at best doing guesswork. It'll be much quicker to test it and get real data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I want to be able to filter the 3V3 power line going out of the ESP32
> MCU*

Well, it seems to me that you have your ferrite bead in the wrong position; it should either be to the right of the 3 parallel capacitors or, form a Pi filter with another set of 3 capacitors to the far left. If forming a Pi filter then it works bidirectionally of course.

But also, you didn't run the AC response up to and beyond 2.4 GHz to see the effect of the ferrite bead (a limited effect I might point out): -

[image]

Simulated circuit: -

[image]

Whether the effect of the dip brings anything to the party I very much doubt. It seems to me that with the capacitors you have, the attenuation would be about 120 dB anyway.

However, if you need a better answer, you should model the capacitors including their self-inductance and resistance. You should also watch out for strong (and undesirable) resonance effects in the low to mid MHz. You should also model the effective loading on the lines in terms of resistance because this will affect the Q factor of resonant peaks (possibly causing device over-stress and maybe failure).

Comment: Thank, yup I realized my range was wrong and updated it in Edit 1 in my post. Our results seem to be the same.

Comment: They should be the same basically but, the notable thing is that the FB (when properly operated as a FB) is not bringing much to the party; just that dip around 2.4 GHz. Its inductance however, is causing the 40 dB/decade slope from the low MHz to over 1 GHz and that by itself is doing pretty much what you might want it to. But, you must adequately model the capacitors.

Comment: holy molly! so I added the series inductance and series resistance for the caps, see edit 2 and what a change I see this makes.

Comment: Yeah, it can become really tricky above 1 GHz. I also think that you need a parallel capacitance of about 22 pF as your smallest value i.e. 1 nF is too big as your smallest value.

Comment: So the smaller the cap the higher frequencies it will attenuate correct?

Comment: @JoeyB the smaller the capacitor, the lower its ESL will be and, the better job it will do at the higher frequencies however, it can't be too small or it becomes ineffective.

Comment: How do I find the ESR and ESL of a capacitor? The values in the sims was on the LTSpice database but I want to try other caps from Digikey and their datasheets do not have the ESR or ESL values

Comment: [Kemet 22 pF capacitor](https://www.kemet.com/en/us/capacitors/ceramic/kc-link/product/C0201C220K8GACTU.html) - use the kemet website because they have good graphs for many capacitors.

Comment: "The smaller the capacitor, the lower its ESL" won't this also be because the lower the cap the higher its resonate frequency of it will be therefore it will have high frequencies it will attenuate?

Comment: Up to a point @JoeyB ("it can't be too small or it becomes ineffective").

Comment: Thanks for the link. What values do I then enter in those fields shown in edit 2? From the link, the ESL value varies with frequency after 1.4GHz but in edit 2 for that cap, the ESL is a fixed value.

Comment: 0.149 ohms for ESR and 28.1 pH for ESL. Just move your cursor over the ESR graph and then select the graph to show ESL and do the same. Both are chosen at the series resonant point i.e. when the graph dips down to a minimum. You can expand the graphs by forming a window around that resonant point.

Comment: @JoeyB Also, typically, the smaller the package the lower the ESL.  ie. 0402 has less inductance than an 0603 package.

Comment: I added the values as per the site (Edit 3), which is really cool! The sims are not that bad, They are no resonant peaks which is a major plus. Also at 2.4GHz, we have an attenuation of -86dB. Which is good.

Comment: @Andyaka can you check if edit 3 is correct?

Comment: @JoeyB it looks about right but given your more recent question and my strong suspicion that LTSpice is using the wrong value of inductance, I have my doubts in a wider sense.

Comment: Yes, I also have doubts about the ferrite bead parameters, However, I will use your suggestion in the post to recalculate those values and simulate them again.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple parallel capacitors should be modeled with their parasitic inductance at the very least.   One capacitor will resonate with the parasitic inductance of the next capacitor to produce amazing peaks and nulls in the total bypassing of the undesired noise.

---

Usually, the old adage of paralleling multiple capacitors of different value are likely to produce LESS, and very frequency dependent affects on the performance.

---

One trick is to add series resistance to each capacitor to De-Q the parasitic unwanted resonances.